# Qt QML - Cannot assign to non-existent property "onClicked"

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm just a beginner on Qt and I trie to do a simple addition calculator. I tried to run it and encounter this : "QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component qrc:/main.qml:74 Cannot assign to non-existent property "onClicked". It also happened for .onTextChanged (when I commented the faulty part).

Here's my code, tell me if you need more than that, sorry if I miss something obvious or if I need to be more specific

Have a great day !

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import Qt.calculatrice 1.0

Window {
id: windo
visible: true
width: 500
height: 300
title: qsTr("Calculatrice")
property alias int1: int1
property alias int2: int2
property alias buttonEgal: buttonEgal

Calculatrice{
    id: calculatrice;
}

Button {
    id: buttonEgal
    x: 277
    y: 130
    text: qsTr("=")
}

Label {
    id: labelResultat
    x: 383
    y: 130
    width: 99
    height: 40
    text: qsTr("Resultat")
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
}

ComboBox {
    id: comboBoxOperator
    x: 104
    y: 130
    width: 70
    height: 40
    textRole: ""
}

TextField {
    id: int1
    x: 17
    y: 130
    width: 81
    height: 40
    text: qsTr("Text Field")
}

TextField {
    id: int2
    x: 188
    y: 130
    width: 83
    height: 40
    text: qsTr("Text Field")
}


int1.onTextChanged:{
    calculatrice.int1 = int1.text
}

int2.onTextChanged: {
    calculatrice.int2 = int2.text
}

buttonEgal.onClicked:{
     calculatrice.addition();
}

}
```

And here's my main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickStyle>
#include "calculatrice.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Calculatrice calculatrice;

    QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");

    qmlRegisterType<Calculatrice>("Qt.calculatrice", 1, 0, "Calculatrice");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create the connection within the Item, for example:

```
Button {
    id: buttonEgal
    x: 277
    y: 130
    text: qsTr("=")
    onClicked: calculatrice.addition()
}
```

Complete Code:

```
Window {
    id: windo
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 300
    title: qsTr("Calculatrice")
    property alias int1: int1
    property alias int2: int2
    property alias buttonEgal: buttonEgal

    Calculatrice{
        id: calculatrice
    }

    Button {
        id: buttonEgal
        x: 277
        y: 130
        text: qsTr("=")
        onClicked: calculatrice.addition()
    }

    Label {
        id: labelResultat
        x: 383
        y: 130
        width: 99
        height: 40
        text: qsTr("Resultat")
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    }

    ComboBox {
        id: comboBoxOperator
        x: 104
        y: 130
        width: 70
        height: 40
        textRole: ""
    }

    TextField {
        id: int1
        x: 17
        y: 130
        width: 81
        height: 40
        text: qsTr("Text Field")
        onTextChanged: calculatrice.int1 = int1.text
    }

    TextField {
        id: int2
        x: 188
        y: 130
        width: 83
        height: 40
        text: qsTr("Text Field")
        onTextChanged: calculatrice.int2 = int2.text
    }
}
```

Or use Connections (although I do not want this option if the object is accessible):

```
Connections{
    target: int1
    onTargetChanged: calculatrice.int1 = int1.text
}

Connections{
    target: int2
    onTargetChanged: calculatrice.int2 = int2.text
}
Connections{
    target: buttonEgal
    onTargetChanged: calculatrice.addition()
}
```